# How to Simulate a mouse/Button Click in c#

Tags: c#, button, click, simulate

I have written a program that amounts to some thousand lines of code and many buttons. I now wish to simulate this code from another Button. I've write a smaller program below to simulate what I want to do. I've looked at other examples it seems as if it would be quite simple to do but HOW!

```
Button1.PerformClick();
```

Wont compile, But how to Simulate a button click?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp13
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Some simulation code clcick button 2/3
            //Button1.PerformClick();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Button1.Clicked");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Button2.Clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to simulate mouse click event or run event click event handler only?

Comment: Do you want to simulate mouse click even. Yes I think? I would like to reuse code rather than go from 1 Thousand lines to 5 thounds, and this is at runtime pls

Comment: Where's your `button1` coming from? Did you have a typo? Show as the code for your designer.cs

Comment: Me Human input will triger button 3 I would then like to have buton 1 code execute and Buttion 2 code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you made a spelling mistake. It should be `button3` instead of `Button3`. The same code worked for me:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button1.Clicked");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button2.Clicked");
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.PerformClick();
    }      
}
```